# Deep Searching / Recursive searching down nodes in AEM/CQ using JSP

Tags: jsp, aem

I want to conditionalise the inclusion of a script file within my head block in an AEM application.

I have my headlibs file, which is included into head.jsp which writes outs my head block.

What I need to do is test if a specific node is set in the content, and if so, include a script file.

For example.

```
<c:if test="${properties['contentNode']}">
    - include a script file.
</c:if>
```

But the scope seems wrong. It can't seem to deep search to **any** content node and check if it's there.

The reason I need a deep, relative, non-specific search is that this contentNode could be placed anywhere on the page, at any level.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `ValueMap properties` will only be populated with the properties of the currentNode.  While `properties.get("child/grandChild/propName")` will work, it is not added to the map of properties until directly accessed.  And it requires you knowing the path explicitly.

Also, `${properties['propName']}` must be a property on a node.  So if you are referencing a path of descendant nodes, fundamentally, the final part of the path must be a property name on a node, not the name of the node itself.

If you don't know the path in advance, you will need the `Resource resource` to iterate and find the desired node that has the property you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Find the resource in the Java code, set it to the request attribute and then use this attribute in the JSTL `<c:if>`:

```
<%
    Resource myResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/some/absolute/path");

    // or use following if you want to check if some child node exists under
    // under current component:
    //
    // Resource myResource = resource.getChild("some/relative/path");

    request.setAttribute("myResource", myResource);
%>

<c:if test="${not empty myResource}">
...
</c:if>
```

I don't encourage to use scriptlets - if the logic for finding your resource is complex, move it to a proper Java class.